# How does MongoDB use JSON Schema keyword "oneOf" for validation?

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Below is defined json schema. I have tested  anyOf, oneOf, allOf. schema works fine in all the cases except oneOf. Ideally it should work only in oneOf. It is not working.

```
{
  "bsonType": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "_id": {},
    "enhanced_file_url": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "child_docs": {
      "type": [
        "array"
      ],
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "additionalProperties": true,
        "properties": {
          "_id": {},
          "standardized_data": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "bsonType": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "shipper__address_line_1": {
                    "bsonType": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bsonType": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "shipper__address_line_2": {
                    "bsonType": "double"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "standardized_field_prediction": {
            "bsonType": "object",
            "additionalProperties": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the input format of json data.

```
{ 
    "enhanced_file_url" : "http://localhost:9000/documents/5ab51e99534b44180e0bdb0c/document_download", 
    "child_docs" : [
    {
        "standardized_data" : {
            "shipper__address_line_1": "A28 pariseema Complex"
        }
    },
    {
        "standardized_data" : {
            "shipper__address_line_2": "A1-63 Orchid Greenfield"
        }
    }
]}
```

When we run above schema it gives error

Comment: I don't know if your schema mongo specific, but for JSON you need a small `t` for `true` as a bare word. As a result of changint `True` to `true`, I then have a valid schema according to https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net, and the instance then passes.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Relequestual since we happen to specify the schema in Python script, we ought to use "True" with a capital T

Comment: Thanks. Just thought I'd check. Can you update your question to include the error message you are seeing please?

Comment: @Relequestual it's not showing any error.. the data gets inserted(correctly validated) when we use "allOf"/"anyOf" while, the document fails validation on "oneOf"

Comment: There's no reason given for validation failure?

Comment: ah... I think I see what's going on here. You need to add `"additionalProperties": False` to your subschemas in your `oneOf`. Let me know if that works and then I'll explain fully in an answer.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

To validate against [`oneOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof), the given data must be valid against *exactly one* of the given subschemas.

The child docs you're trying to insert, satisfy both of the criteria you provide in the `oneOf` field, in that they are objects:

`child_docs[0]` satisfies **both** `oneOf[0]` and `oneOf[1]`, **in that it's an object**.

So you should use [`anyOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof) instead.

Comment: Please add more explanation. You are implying the reader knows: `To validate against oneOf, the given data must be valid against *exactly one* of the given subschemas.`